# 3d point generation

Tags: perl, graphics, 3d, points

I would like to generate a cube of 3D points with x,y,z coordinates, which are spaced equally. I wrote the following program in Perl, but when I visualise, it looks some points are missing.

```
for($x=0;$x<28;$x+=1.4){
    for($y=0;$y<28;$y+=1.4){
        for($z=0;$z<28;$z+=1.4){
            @arr_grid[$g]=$x."       ".$y."       ".$z."\n";
            $g++;
        }
    }
}
$c=scalar @arr_grid;
for($l=0;$l<$c;$l++){
    print "HETATM      O                 @arr_grid[$l]\n";
}
```

or suggest me any books or sites which deals with 3D points in space and calculations. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "it looks some points are missing"? How are you visualizing it?

Comment: Actually its related to biological molecules, i.e bioinformatics, Im visualising by bioinfo tools. If possible tell me where to read this kind of stuff.

Comment: Well the code looks clean to me and certainly creates 21*21*21 points. I think the mistake is not in this code.

Comment: This may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775050/print-output-in-predefined-format-perl/8775228

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in seeing something that looks more like how a Perl programmer would write this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @arr_grid;

for (my $x = 0; $x < 28; $x += 1.4) {
  for (my $y = 0; $y < 28; $y += 1.4) {
    for (my $z = 0; $z < 28; $z += 1.4) {

      push @arr_grid, "$x       $y       $z\n";
    }
  }
}

foreach (@arr_grid) {
  say "HETATM      O                 $_";
}
```

But, like Nick says, it doesn't seem to be a problem with the Perl.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but my major prob is i have same set of points with different values of x,y,z, what sud i do to calculate distance between points of both sets ?